# How to make random string replace textview?

Tags: java, android, string, random, android-studio

I have an activity with 3 edittexts and a button.
I have a second activity with 2 textviews.

When button is clicked i want two random edittexts values from activity1 to replace the text on textviews on activity2.

I managed to do that, but not randomly. How can I make it random?

Here is the first activity.

```
final EditText et  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick (View v){
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, postavke.class);
                i.putExtra("prvi", et.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("drugi", et1.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("treci", et2.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the second activity.

```
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdf);
    tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("prvi"));

TextView dr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdg);
dr.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("drugi"));
```

Comment: what do you mean by *randomly* ?

Comment: I think he has 2 slots, 3 values and wants to use 2 of the 3 values, randomly selected

Comment: @Tomo Can both the `TextView` contain same values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second activity:

```
String[] texts = new String[]{
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("prvi"),
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("drugi"),
    getIntent().getExtras().getString("treci"),
};

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdf);
TextView dr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdg);

Random random = new Random();
tv.setText(texts[random.nextInt(3)]);
dr.setText(texts[random.nextInt(3)]);
```

Or, for unique values:

First activity:

```
final EditText et  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick (View v){

            ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
            texts.add(et.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et1.getText().toString());
            texts.add(et2.getText().toString());

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, postavke.class);
            i.putExtra("texts", texts);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Second activity:

```
ArrayList<String> texts = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("texts");

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdf);
TextView dr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdg);

Collections.shuffle(texts);
tv.setText(texts.get(0));
dr.setText(texts.get(1));
```

Comment: it is possible that random number generate same number . it is better that just create a random number and delete it s index from array like this:
texts.remove[random.nextInt(3)]]; and then use other texts array elements.

Comment: This should work, but there is a 33% chance the strings will be the same

Comment: Just posted the simplest answer! There was no mention of wanting them to be unique

Comment: @JoeFrostick Thanks for the code, yesterday it was fine, but today i realised Tim Castelijns was right, I do need them to be unique. Could you please edit the code so that one string doesn't show twice on the screen in the same time? Sorry that I didn't pay attention earlier.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The new answer also shows how you could send the array list as a while, reducing the number of argument values you need to remember

Comment: @JoeFrostick It works. If my app ever gets on google play and you have to pay for it, I'll make sure you have it for no cost. Thanks man, you're the best!!

Answer (score 0):

Add your Strings(Eg : `getIntent().getExtras().getString("prvi"`)) from previous Activity to a `ArrayList`.

Then do simply `Collection.shuffle(your_list);`

Get items from `ArrayList` & set it to your `TextViews`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare an array that will contain the values:

`public String[] randomAnswers = new String[3]; //3 because you said you have 3 random strings`

2. In your onCreate() add the values to the array:

   `randomAnswers[0] = getIntent().getExtras().getString("prvi");
   randomAnswers[1] = getIntent().getExtras().getString("drugi");
   randomAnswers[2] = getIntent().getExtras().getString("treci");`
3. Select two random values:

`private static final Random RANDOM = new Random(); //in java.util package`

Inside onCreate:

```
final int randomInt1 = RANDOM.nextInt(3); //nextInt(int) goes from 0 to int-1, considering arrays start at index=0 we want to get a random number from: 0, 1, 2
int randomInt2;
do {
        randomInt2 = RANDOM.nextInt(3);
} while (randomInt1 == randomInt2);
final String firstRandomString = values[randomInt1];
final String secondRandomString = values[randomInt2];`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use some thing like this the edited form of @Joe Frostick answere:

```
String[] texts = new String[]{
getIntent().getExtras().getString("prvi"),
getIntent().getExtras().getString("drugi"),
getIntent().getExtras().getString("treci"),
                             };

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdf);
TextView dr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asdg);

Random random = new Random();
texts.remove(random.nextInt(3));
tv.setText(texts[0]);
dr.setText(texts[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, I really didn't expect so many answers in not much time. You're the best!

Comment: That's the point of StackOverflow. All fo us also post questions one day or another. And trying to answer questions is a good way to learn new features ;) hava a ncie day